# Taking Tylenol on a Taanith: Defining "ill"

Tags: halacha, shabbat, medicine, fast-days, choleh-sick

With regard to *hilkhoth shabbath*, a *choleh she'ein bo sakana* (one with a non-life-threatening illness) is allowed to engage in therapeutic activites, such as taking medication. This is not the case with regard to a *meichush* (minor discomfort) because of a Rabbinic prohibition of performing therapies on Shabbath (*refuah*; see *Shemirath Shabbath KeHilchatha* 34:1,3 cited by http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Medicine_on_Shabbat). A generally accepted criterion to distinguish between these two classes of affliction is whether one would lie down because of the illness (see *Mishnah Berurah* 328:121 and Rabbi Dovid Ribiat's "The 39 *Melachos*" vol. 2 p. 492).

Separately, we find that by fasts other than Yom Kippur, a *choleh she'ein bo sakana* is not obligated to fast (see *Shulchan Arukh* 554:4). By analogy, shouldn't this mean that anyone who would lie down because of how he feels should not be obligated to fast (and, at the very least, should be allowed to take, e.g., caffeine pills or Tylenol to reduce or preempt, e.g., a caffeine-withdrawal headache)? If not, what is the reason to distinguish between these two areas?

Comment: Sources for your many claims would increase the value of this post

Comment: Tish'a B'Av is another exception where there is a stricter fast level. I'm particualrlay curious about your source of using the "lying down" criteria as the standard.

Comment: @DanF A choleh she'eyn bo sakana is also not obligated to fast on tisha b'av. I believe poskim try to distinguish Tisha B'Av with regard to pregnant or nursing women who don't qualify as choleh she'eyn bo sakana. see the Aruch HaShulchan...

Comment: Who says one cannot use pills? From the fact that we generally do not require swallowed pills to be kosher, do we not see that they are not considered food?

Comment: @wfb The Star-K seems reluctant to give a blanket *heter* for non-kosher pills *l'chatchila* for a *meichush* (implying they would for a *choleh*?): http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-medi-guide.htm#fA

Comment: @wfb Then why is it not accepted to take caffeine pills on fast days? (and what about on Yom Kippur?)

Comment: http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Medications#Taking_Pills_on_a_Fast_Day

Comment: http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/110,2821/Is-it-permitted-to-take-medicine-on-a-fast-day.html

Comment: @wfb The implication of the halachipedia articel is that one should avoid l'chatchila e.g. taking caffeine pills on the fast itself (b'shem Nechamas Yisroel 27:22 ?). That AskMoses psak though is quite interesting. Is it clear he also means meychush?

Comment: @wfb how reliable is Ask Moses?  They don't cite any sources in that answer.

Comment: @Loewian Analogies are good, but what about trying to define the parameters of the "*bulmos*" brought in the sources and in the Rambam? I think I remember reading that he defines it in his Commentary to the Mishnah as dizziness, headaches, et al.

Comment: See igrot moshe orach chaim 3:91 end, where he says that a choleh she'ein bo sakanah can take pills because it's שלא כדרך אכילה (implying that a non choleh cannot)

Comment: @wfb and perhaps implying that anyone who would lie down from how they feel otherwise, should be allowed to take caffeine pills even on yom kippur...

Comment: According to [Rabbi Doniel Neustadt](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5758/balak.html) one may take tylenol on a fast day.

> When suffering from a severe headache, etc., aspirin or Tylenol, etc.,
> may be taken. The poskim, however, do not permit taking those
> medications with water, unless the water is first made to have a bad
> taste

Comment: @wfb http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Display.asp?ClipDate=3/8/2009

Comment: "Sisit: Checking the Strings Each Morning"?

Comment: @wfb I'm still getting: "A person suffering from a headache on a fast day may take pain relieving pills. If possible, he should ingest the pills without water. However, Hacham Ovadia Yosef rules that if one cannot swallow pills without water, then he may use a small sip of water, though preferably he should try ingesting the pills without water."

Comment: @wfb http://www.aish.com/h/9av/oal/48964976.html seem to allow pills on tisha b'av to prevent a meichush: "12. May one take pills on Shabbat to alleviate the pains of fasting?

It is permitted to take them on Shabbat until sunset only if they are mixed with a food or drink. One should preferably prepare the mixture before Shabbat.

One may take them without water even on Saturday night, unless they are pleasant tasting."

Comment: https://kollel.com/fasting-pills/